# match results of SQL Query with JSON result from Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: json, powershell

I have two JSON files that i need to match for similar data and return only the matching data.  1 file is a result of a SQL query and another is a result of a Invoke-RestMethod Get request

i have tried to store the different json data into arrays but i am able to drill down properly into the JSON objects

[Here are the two JSON Files] 
SQL Query results JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "OnCallTeamName":  "1 Park Ave Support Corporate Desktop Support Teams",
        "ContactPrimaryLoginID":  "chungn03",
        "ContactSecondaryLoginID":  "chungn03",
        "FirstEscalationLoginID":  "giakog01",
        "SecondaryEscalationLoginID":  null
    },
    {
        "OnCallTeamName":  "14 Wall Street Support Corporate Desktop Support Teams",
        "ContactPrimaryLoginID":  "gendua01",
        "ContactSecondaryLoginID":  "gendua01",
        "FirstEscalationLoginID":  "giakog01",
        "SecondaryEscalationLoginID":  null
    },
        "OnCallTeamName":  "WUH Technology Managers",
        "ContactPrimaryLoginID":  "corond01",
        "ContactSecondaryLoginID":  "carela02",
        "FirstEscalationLoginID":  "corond01",
        "SecondaryEscalationLoginID":  null
    },
    {
        "OnCallTeamName":  "Xper",
        "ContactPrimaryLoginID":  "greenj23",
        "ContactSecondaryLoginID":  "greenj23",
        "FirstEscalationLoginID":  "daniet02",
        "SecondaryEscalationLoginID":  null
    }
]
```

REST call JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "group_name":  "Outage Management Team",
        "group_onlinemembers":  [
                                    {
                                        "user_username":  "moraly01",
                                        "user_firstname":  "Yvette",
                                        "user_lastname":  "Morales",
                                        "user_id":  "58"
                                    }
                                ]
    },
    {
        "group_name":  "Ivanti HEAT",
        "group_onlinemembers":  [
                                    {
                                        "user_username":  "vasquj01",
                                        "user_firstname":  "Jose",
                                        "user_lastname":  "Vasquez",
                                        "user_id":  "148"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "user_username":  "moraly01",
                                        "user_firstname":  "Yvette",
                                        "user_lastname":  "Morales",
                                        "user_id":  "58"
                                    }
                                ]
    },
    {
        "group_name":  "Telecommunications",
        "group_onlinemembers":  [
                                    {
                                        "user_username":  "moraly01",
                                        "user_firstname":  "Yvette",
                                        "user_lastname":  "Morales",
                                        "user_id":  "58"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "user_username":  "fernad04",
                                        "user_firstname":  "David",
                                        "user_lastname":  "Fernandez",
                                        "user_id":  "150"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "user_username":  "efg213",
                                        "user_firstname":  "Edwin",
                                        "user_lastname":  "Guerrero",
                                        "user_id":  "76"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "user_username":  "reyesl07",
                                        "user_firstname":  "Louis",
                                        "user_lastname":  "Reyes",
                                        "user_id":  "75"
                                    }
                                ]
    },
    {
        "group_name":  "NYU Data Center Operations",
        "group_onlinemembers":  [

                                ]
    }
]
```

I need to know how to use powershell to loop through these JSON Files and only pull out the matching items

Comment: The two given json examples seem to match at absolutely nothing.. Please clarify your question and have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I realize that the data may not match.  My question is how would one go about searching through each json array to look for matches